# Jquery scrollTo issues in IE7

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7, scrollto

I have a page that uses jQuery's scrollTo plugin to manage some functionality. When you want to reset your password from the login page, it scrolls to a new form rather than taking the user to a new page. It all works fine everywhere but IE7, of course. Here's my HTML:

```
<div id="blocksWrapper">
    <div id="blocks">
        <div id="form" class="block">
            <form id="formLogin" action="../index.html" method="post">
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Registered Members Log-in Here</legend>
                    <label for="formLoginEmail">Email Address</label>
                    <input type="text" id="formLoginEmail" name="formLoginEmail" value="Email Address" />
                    <label for="formLoginPassword">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" id="formLoginPassword" name="formLoginPassword" value="Password" />
                    <input type="image" src="../images/login/buttonLogin.png" value="Login" id="formLoginSubmit" name="formLoginSubmit" />
                </fieldset>
            </form>
            <h3 id="register"><a href="#">Register</a></h3>
            <h3 id="forgot"><a href="#">Forgot Password?</a></h3>
        </div><!--end form-->
        <div id="password" class="block">
            <form id="formPassword" action="../index.html" method="post">
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Forgot your password?</legend>
                    <h3>Enter your Email Address to reset your password</h3>
                    <p>By selecting &lsquo;Reset Password&rsquo; you certify that the email address contained in this field is your email address.</p>
                    <label for="formPasswordEmail">Email Address</label>
                    <input type="text" id="formPasswordEmail" name="formPasswordEmail" value="Email Address" />
                    <input type="image" src="../images/login/buttonResetPassword.png" value="Reset Password" id="formPasswordSubmit" name="formLoginSubmit" />
                </fieldset>
            </form>                                
        </div><!--end password-->
        <div id="confirm" class="block">
            <h2>Confirmation Sent</h2>
            <h3>Please check your email for instructions <br />on resetting your password.</h3>
            <p>Your confirmation email will come from donotreply@mygrizzly.com. Be sure to add this to your spam filter so you will be able to receive this email.</p>
            <h4><a href="#">Return to login screen</a></h4>
        </div><!--end confirm-->
    </div><!--end blocks-->
</div>
```

My CSS (all that should matter):

```
.login #content #blocksWrapper {
    background: url(../images/login/bgBlock.png);
    height: 127px;
    margin: 0 0 50px 9px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 20px 18px;
    width: 437px;
}

.login #content #blocks {
    height: 127px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 1377px;
}

.login #content .block {
    float: left;
    height: 127px;
    margin-right: 18px;
    position: relative;
    width: 441px;
}
```

And my jQuery:

```
$('#forgot a').click(function() {
    $('#blocksWrapper').scrollTo({left: 459, top: 0}, 400);
    return false;
});

$('#formPasswordSubmit').click(function() {
    $('#blocksWrapper').scrollTo({left: 918, top: 0}, 400);
    return false;
});

$('#confirm h4 a').click(function() {
    $('#blocksWrapper').scrollTo({left: 0, top: 0}, 200);
    return false;
});
```

The code excerpts live on this page: [redacted when fixed]

As you can see, it works fine in all browsers other than IE7. In IE7, it's scrolling the background of the #blocksWrapper div rather than the contents of the #blocks div. IE7 is also not hiding the overflow for some reason. Anyone have any ideas?

I've tried testing using #blocks as my jQuery selector, and that isn't the issue.

Thanks a ton,
Marcus

Comment: @markus remove `#blocksWrapper #blocks` - `overflow:hidden;` tested with developers tool for IE

Comment: I saw no change either changing the main style sheet or removing that property via the IE developer tool. Just to confirm, you want me to remove the overflow property from .login #content #blocks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by adding position:relative to the wrapper element.

```
.login #content #blocksWrapper {
    background: url(../images/login/bgBlock.png);
    height: 127px;
    margin: 0 0 50px 9px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 20px 18px;
    position: relative;
    width: 437px;
}
```